# javascript file doesn't get included from ng-header

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-include

I am new to `angularJS`. I have an html header file which i am including in all other html files using `ng-include`. I have a JS file included in the header file. Whenever i am clicking on `li` element of that header file, a function of that header file should get invoked. But i think that the JS file itself is not getting invoked because i have written an `alert box` in `document ready` itself but it's not invoking. I have included the js file in the right folder.

*Header.html*

```
<html ng-app="header">
<script src="./js/header.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body ng-controller="maincontroller">
 <li ng-click="logout_off()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</li>
</body>
</html>
```

*Header.js*

```
var header = angular.module('header', []);

header.controller('maincontroller', function($scope, $http) {
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        alert("HI");

        $scope.logout_off = function() {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'logout_service',
                dataType: 'json',

            }).sucess(function(data) {
                alert(data);
                window.location = 'index.html';

            })
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: Try setting controller as ng-controller="maincontroller as cont", then in ng-click="cont.logout_off()"

Comment: yes i did. But the function in js file is not executing.Should i add an achor tag or is it ok with the li ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the controller to your HTML.

Try adding `ng-controller="maincontroller"` in your header html.

EDIT: Make sure your loading the header.js script within your index html.

Comment: i have already added it in the body tag and ng-app="header" in the html tag

Comment: Can you post the rest of your mark up and script please?

Comment: Added the rest of the html.

Comment: Is there any error in the console you see ? I do not see angular library getting loaded in your code.

Comment: @ShripadAshtekar, Try to get rid of `angular.element(document).ready` function

Comment: Okay . i will try and get back ASAP

Comment: I did . But it is not executing.

Comment: May be you can create plunkr with all your code ? We will see what fails exactly.

Comment: Actually this is a small logout functionality of a whole project. And the code i 've provided is the whole code

Answer (score 0):

Directly define the function `logout_off` with the `$scope`. You don't need to use `document-ready`, so remove it.

*Use*

```
var header = angular.module('header', []);
header.controller('maincontroller', function($scope, $http) {
    //You don't need this function
    //angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    //    alert("HI");
    //});

    $scope.logout_off = function() {
      //Your code
    }
});
```

Comment: I did . But it is not executing.